# WPF Gridview Zindex

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, datepicker, z-index

I have a datepicker control that I am using to set a date field in a gridview control, my datepicker shows a date and a button to display a calendar you can use to pick a date. This works great on its own but when I add this to a gridview the calendar pops up and the  columns and rows cover up parts of the calendar. Setting the ZIndex for the calendar doesn't help because the other rows are on different panels? How can I get around this? I tried raising the ZIndex of the VisualParent but no luck.

Update, the gridview is very standard, 4 columns one of which is a date column, the datatemplate for that column creates a datepicker which initially looks like a text box and a button, the button is placed on a canvas panel and when clicked a calendar is added to the canvas. The canvas is the only panel that allows its children to stretch over its own boundaries so the button is 10 x 10 or so and the calendar is 200 x 200. When the calendar pops up it normally just covers up adjacent fields but when placed on a gridview each cell of the gridview that is "after" the datepicker covers up the calendar. I'm supposing I need to raise the zindex of my cell but I can't find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this should be done using a popup or an expander.

Answer (score 2):

Could you provide more info about gridview and datepicker? Especially are they your custom controls or do they belong to any open source or commercial libraries or separate?

You also mentioned that DataTemplate has Canvas as a panel. Even though a Canvas can contain large elements, it does not necessarily show all of its children. This may or may not relate to your problem, though.

P.S. Sorry I had to post this as an answer. My reputation does not allow me to comment?